# How to write a "reusable" function for google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to do the same operations on different cells and I am trying to write a generic script. I give a trivial example that explains my problem below.

Let's say that I want to click on a button and decrease the value of the cell A1 by 1. That's straightforward. I define the following function

```
function dec_cell_def(){
  var cell = fr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1")
  cell.setValue(cell.getValue() - 1)
}
```

Then assign the "script" `dec_cell_def` to any button and I am done.

Let's say now, that I want to do this for many different cells. I could of course write a function for each one, but this is hardly a solution. So I thought the following would work. I define the function `cell_dec` that take as an argument the label of a cell and returns a function that decreases the value of the cell:

```
function dec_cell(label){
  () => {
    var cell = fr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(label)
    cell.setValue(cell.getValue() - 1)
  }
}
```

However when I assign the "script" `dec_cell("A1")` to a button, I am told that the script does not exist. What is the proper way to do that?

PS. I know that I can get the selected cell and act on it, but I would like to have a fixed target for my function.

Edit: I meant that I want to do this for few cells but not all at once. I would like to create a button for each cell and I would like to avoid copy-pasting the same code. I think that none of the suggested questions answer that.

Comment: See linked answers. You can dynamically create functions in a loop(say `dec_cell_a1`,`dec_cell_b1`,...) and assign them. If that's not what you're looking for, [edit] your question to explain why the answers don't satisfy your question.

Comment: @TheMaster don't feel it is quite the answer here. Even if the OP makes the menus, the current code is not going to work for multiple cells.

Comment: @Marios If OP feels otherwise, I'll reopen this question. I interpreted `I want to do this for many different cells.` to mean multiple buttons individually acting on  their respective cells. Your solution doesn't do that.

Comment: @TheMaster I might be mistaken. By the way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64976479/11225291) I have written a similar solution. By using `onSelectionChange` trigger you can click on a cell and increment the value next to it. The solution can be easily modified, instead of setting the word "button" you can set an cell image of a button there to make it more fancy. Check this out if you have some free time.

Comment: @TheMaster I added an explanation. I hope it is clear now

Comment: I think it's clear from your explanations, That the duplicates were the answer. The first question creates new functions on the go, so that you can assign them manually or programmatically. But the easiest way is to use a trigger: `onEdit`+ checkbox or `onSelectionChange`+image as suggested in the second and third duplicate answers. Try and see.

Comment: @TheMaster I understand that the questions are related, but I would argue that they are not duplicate, in the sense that I have spent a couple of hours and I cannot figure out the solution.

Comment: @tst If you have a specific problem implementing the solution(s) provided, you need to explain more than `none of the suggested questions answer that`. Show what you've tried and why it doesn't work. Or even ask a new question explaining the specific aspect. Currently @Marios seemed to have directed you towards  the linked answer and it is working for you. Is that right? Or do you still  have problems?

Comment: @TheMaster I may do that when I will look into that again, I don't think I can waste more time with it now