# Google Sheets - multiple increment buttons

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to add buttons to a Google Sheet that allow me to increment or decrement a cell value.

I have gone through [tutorials like the one here](https://productivityspot.com/spin-button-google-sheets/), and [answers on Stack Overflow like the one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813855/increment-cell-value-by-one-by-clicking), however each of these talks about manually drawing shapes and assigning code to those shapes.

My situation has 2 problems with this approach:

- I want to be able to add increment and decrement buttons to lots of
  cells without having to draw and encode each button.
- The drawing tools in Google Sheets is fairly basic and redrawing the same sized
  button each time is proving to be difficult at best.

In trying to come up with a solution to this situation I have considered a few things.  The "buttons" don't have to look like buttons for my purposes, if I can trigger code by clicking on a cell this will suffice.

Hopefully there is a programatic way to create these buttons in Google Sheets, that would be ideal.  However at this point I would just settle for better drawing tools so I can at least have identical shaped buttons.

Is there a better approach to adding multiple increment buttons to Google Sheets?

Comment: Would you mind using the sidebar and making the button like this `<input type="button" value="increment" onClick="google.script.run.increment();" />` and it increments the value of the current selected cell by one if it is a number.  You can use the same button on all pages

Answer (score 1):

#### Using the SideBar

Works on any page

Apps Script:

```
function increment() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  const v = cell.getValue();
  if (!isNaN(v)) {
    cell.setValue(Number(v) + 1);
  }
}

function showMySidebar() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("sidebar"))
}
```

HTML: (sidebar.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sidebar Buttons</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="increment" onClick="google.script.run.increment();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Demo:

[image]

With what you have here adding the decrement should be a breeze

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative Solution #1: Register Scripts as Macros

You may bind scripts as Google Sheets macros for faster results. For a quick guide on macros with Google Apps Script, you may view the [Google Sheets Macro](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros) page.

### Script

You may bind the following scripts:

```
function increaseValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValues();
  var out = values.map(x=>x.map(y=>parseInt(y)+1));
  ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().setValues(out);
}

function decreaseValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValues();
  var out = values.map(x=>x.map(y=>parseInt(y)-1));
  ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().setValues(out);
}
```

### Output:

For the script's function, I bound them to ctrl+alt+shift+1 and ctrl+alt+shift+2 macros.

[image: output1]

NOTE: As what can be seen in the demonstration, the script would return `#NUM!` when the cell is empty.

### Alternative Solution #2: You may use Check Boxes

I noticed that you can automate the addition and removal of check boxes using the `insertCheckboxes()` and `removeCheckboxes()` functions, respectively. So I had this idea wherein you may use check boxes as a substitute for buttons if you want to generate multiple check boxes.

### Script

For this, an onEdit() script (which you may use as the basis for your code) is used.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if (column == 1) {
    try {
      if (e.value.length > 0) {
        ss.toast('Adding Checkboxes');
        ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2,1,2).insertCheckboxes();
      }
    }
    catch {
     ss.toast('Removing Checkboxes');
     ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2,1,2).removeCheckboxes();
    }
  }
  else if (column == 2) {
    var value = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,).getValue() + 1;
    ss.toast('Increase Value');
    ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,).setValue(value);
  }
  else if (column == 3) {
    var value = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,).getValue() -1;
    ss.toast('Decrease Value');
    ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,).setValue(value);
  }
}
```

### Output

I have made a test case for the script wherein a user will add numerical values to column A which triggers the generation of check boxes in its corresponding columns B and C.

[image: add check box]

Removing a value in column A would remove the check boxes.

[image: remove]

Changing the values of the check boxes from false to true and vice versa will trigger the increment or decrement of values (as seen below):

[image: functionality]

References:

- [Google Sheets Macro](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros)
- [Class Range: insertCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcheckboxes)
- [Class Range: removeCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removecheckboxes)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have other questions.